# Google Sheets vlookup cannot find value error on date match

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have two sheets ('Car' and 'Gas Data') in a google sheets document.

Each has dates in column A. When I add a new date in a row in 'Car', a want to autofill the value in column D from the sheet 'Gas Data' with the matching date row.

My failing vlookup: =VLOOKUP(A2,'Ohio Gas Data'!A:D,4,FALSE)

I am getting the error: "Did not find value '44352' in VLOOKUP evaluation." but the value in A2 is a date and I have formatted both columns for dates.

How can I edit the above vlookup to select A2 in 'Car', match it with a date in column A of 'Gas Data', then select the value from Column D?

Comment: My guess is that the data in 'Gas Data' is text-that-looks-like-dates.

Comment: I did manually set both columns to date only. It appears that the 44352 number is coming from a misread from A2 in the 'Car' sheet. But if I have set it as a date, I am not sure how to fix that. I am doing a little googling about text-that-looks-like-dates and I am not seeing anything yet. But I will keep looking. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample sheet with your input and desired output so we can easily replicate your concern?  Remove sensitive information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try with this. Even if it's a text or a date with time (meaning that instead of 44352 you have 44352.6012 for example), you can try with:

```
=XLOOKUP(DATEVALUE(A2),INDEX(DATEVALUE('Ohio Gas Data'!A:A)),'Ohio Gas Data'!D:D,"No match",0)
```

It should round or convert both the column and the value in A2 to make them match. I added an option of "No match" so you have the "feedback"
Let me know!

Comment: That did it! I have no idea why sheets doesn't like my date. But that fixed the problem. Thanks.